# Prestashop 1.5.6 Link::getImageLink returns unexpected value

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I'm calling

> $imagePath = Link::getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $id_product,
>   'home_default');

For example, when the $id_product is 150 , it returns websitepath/img/p/1/5/0/150-home_default.jpg . But when I see the real image_link created for that product id with the browser view source option it's websitepath/img/p/1/2/5/125-home_default.jpg . Isnt that code supposed to return the image links for a product?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getImageLink` method returns a link to a product image, but the link contains the ID of the image (125) not the ID of the product(150).

The second argument of the method call should be the image ID not the product ID.

First you should get the image ID then you can get the image link:

```
$image = Image::getCover($id_product);
$imagePath = Link::getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $image['id_image'], 'home_default');
```

Answer (score 4):

In Prestashop 1.6, getImageLink shouldn't be call statically

```
$image = Product::getCover((int)$data['id_product']);
$link = new Link;//because getImageLInk is not static function
$data['imagePath'] = $image ? 'http://'.$link->getImageLink($data['link_rewrite'], $image['id_image'], 'medium_default') : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

`getImageLInk` is not static function, so the solid way is

```
$image = Image::getCover($id_product);
$product = new Product($id_product, false, Context::getContext()->language->id);
$link = new Link();//because getImageLInk is not static function
$imagePath = $link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $image['id_image'], 'home_default');
```